# Mask Moeda Input readonly

Tags: php, html, jquery

Gostaria de saber como posso estar colocando máscara de moeda, ja que meu input="campoResultado" é bloqueado e adicionado valor automaticamente após colocado um valor no input acima.

Tentei adicionar a mascara no próprio input="campoResultado", mas sem sucesso.

Obrigado!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <title>Título da página</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.11/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

        <script>
function troca(valor){
var campo1 = document.getElementById("ncorridas").value;
var resultado = parseFloat(campo1);
resultado = resultado*5400;
document.getElementById('campoResultado').value = ('R$ ') + resultado + (' reais por ano!');
}
</script>
<b>Número de corridas por dia <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="number" name="ncorridas" id="ncorridas" min="0" onChange="troca(this.value)" />
  </head>
  <body>
    Valor:<input readonly="true" class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" name="campoResultado" id="campoResultado" /></b>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Convertendo números para moeda sem framework

**1 - Solução aproveitando seu script**

Com apenas mais 3 linhas de javascript puro na sua função se obtém o resultado esperado.

```js
function troca(valor){
var campo1 = document.getElementById("ncorridas").value;
var resultado = parseFloat(campo1);
//formata para duas casas decimais utilizando notação de ponto fixo
resultado = (resultado*5400).toFixed(2);
//substitui separador decimal ponto por virgula
resultado=resultado.replace(".", ",");
//a regex abaixo coloca um ponto a esquerda de cada grupo de 3 digitos desde que não seja no inicio do numero
resultado = resultado.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");

document.getElementById('campoResultado').value = ('R$ ') + resultado + (' por ano!');
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web" rel="stylesheet">
<b>Número de corridas por dia <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="number" name="ncorridas" id="ncorridas" min="0" onChange="troca(this.value)" />
  </head>
  <body>
    Valor:<input readonly="true" class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" name="campoResultado" id="campoResultado" /></b>
```

**2 - Para navegadores modernos utilize [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)** - Converte um número em uma cadeia de caracteres usando a localidade atual ou especificada.

Para formatar o valor em `Moeda` configure .`toLocaleString()` com `minimumFractionDigits` e `maximumFractionDigits`

- `minimumFractionDigits` - exibe a parte fracionária com quantidade mínima de dígitos.
- `maximumFractionDigits` - exibe a parte fracionária com quantidade máxima de dígitos.

```js
const [corridas, Valor] = [...document.querySelectorAll('input.w3-border')];
       
       function formatar$(moeda) {
          return moeda.toLocaleString('pt-BR',{style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL'}, {
          minimumFractionDigits: 2,
          maximumFractionDigits: 2
          });
       }


       corridas.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
         const moeda = Number(this.value);
         const _Valor = moeda * 5400;
         Valor.value = formatar$(_Valor) + ' por ano';
       });
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web" rel="stylesheet">

    <b>Número de corridas por dia <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="number" name="ncorridas" id="ncorridas" min="0"/>

    Valor:<input readonly="true" class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" name="campoResultado" id="campoResultado" /></b>
```

> Retirei a palavra `reais` do resultado porque já consta o simbolo `R$`, mas isso fica a seu critério!